# Release "source" folder in System.IO.Compression.ZipFile

Tags: .net, powershell, zip

I have a small PowerShell script that takes a folder, copies some files over to a temporary folder, ZIPs them together and then deletes the temporary folder.

I have to do this through a temporary folder because I need to manipulate some files prior to zipping them, and I don't want to do that on the "original" source files.

Here is my script:

```
function CreateZip
{
    param([string]$source, [string]$target)
    Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"
    if (Test-Path $target) {
        Remove-Item $target
    }
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $target)
}
```

While this works perfectly, it seems that `CreateFromDirectory` places a lock on the source directory that is never released (until powershell exits). I think so because I am unable to delete the directory through my script. It says:

```
Directory C:\Users\\****\AppData\Local\Temp\c12ddd2f cannot be removed because it is not empty.
```

If I use the same method of deleting, after my script has exited, it works. Apparently because PowerShell releases it's resources.

Can I somehow force it to release it's locks while the script is still running?

I delete the folder using this command:

```
Remove-Item $tmpDir -Recurse
```

Comment: Hi, does the `-Force` parameter change anything ?

Comment: No, still gives the same error.

Comment: That was what I was thinking too, but it's kinda hard to achieve: I don't get any reference back and the call is just a static method of the class. And - afaik - I cannot "unload" a whole type / assembly, or can I?

Comment: No, never mind, the method returns void, not a disposable ZipFile.

Comment: I have the same problem. No solution?

Comment: Not really. I started a second PS instance to zip the file. Which, upon completing, closes it's handle. Or use dotNetZip, but it adds an external dependency.